# JavaFX: stage.getIcons().add() not working in a JavaFX app

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I want to add a program icon for my JavaFX app. I know how to do it - I have a Stage object defined as a field in the main app class:

```
private Stage stage;
```

And then in the method that is initilaizing the main stage I have a piece of code:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:view/images/programicon.png"));
primaryStage.show();
```

I have a package `com.myapp.view`, and in this package I have another package: `com.myapp.view.images`, and I have pasted the icon I wanted to use, called `programicon.png`. Earlier, I had written it wrong:

```
primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("view/images/programicon.png"));
```

And I got an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1110)
```

But when I changed the url to `file:view/images/programicon.png` - there is no exception now, but the program icon still remains default.

The `programicon.png` is a 512x512 image without background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution. Changing from:

```
primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:view/images/programicon.png"));
```

To

```
primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("view/images/programicon.png")));
```

did the trick.